# In robot framework , for API Automation in delete call ,both strings are equal but got != error and my test failed

Tags: python-3.x, automation, robotframework

In robot framework , for API Automation in delete call ,both strings are equal but got != error and my test failed. I tried multiple ways to solve this issue but no luck.

[image]

output:
[image]

Comment: It looks like those two strings are truly not equal, so robot seems to be working as expected. The left hand ends with `with Id` and the right hand ends with `with Id ' '`.

Comment: Again I found this error.

Comment: Mandatory parameter name not provided for Subscriber  != Mandatory parameter name not provided for Subscriber